Laravel multiple files (images) validation
I want posts to be able to have multiple images, so I have these validation rules:
class StorePostRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'title' => ['required', 'min:3', 'max:50'],
            'caption' => ['required', 'string'],
            'images.*' => ['nullable', 'image', 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg', 'max:1024']
        ];
    }
}

but for some reason when the user sends other than image files no validation error is thrown:

this is my PostController store method:
public function store(StorePostRequest $request)
    {
        $post = new Post($request->safe()->except('images'));

        $post->user()->associate(auth()->user());

        $post->save();

        if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
            $post->addAllMediaFromRequest()->each(fn($image) => $image->toMediaCollection('posts_imgs'));
        }

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Post has been created successfully.',
            'post' => new PostResource($post)
        ]);
    }

is there a way to make sure all data sent under images key are images or null?

do you want to allow null values when at least 1 image is in the array?

I want to allow the user not to post any images in the post, and allow him to post multiple images if he wanted, but I don't know if these something wrong with these validation rules.

does your current implementation filter out wrong values? It is just not throwing an error? In controller do dd($request->validated());

I think the validation error should be thrown in the form request and the request shouldn't even reach the controller in this case, but this is what I get when having return $request->validated(); in the controller: {     "title": "test",     "caption": "test",     "images": [         {},         {}     ] }

Understanding the Issue
When dealing with file uploads in Laravel, the Request object handles files and text inputs differently:

Text Inputs: Stored in the input bag, accessed via $request->input().
Files: Stored in the files bag, accessed via $request->file().

Behavior with Array Fields (e.g., images[]):
If you have an array field like images[] in your form and both files and text inputs are submitted under this field, Laravel's behavior can vary:

When the number of files is greater than or equal to the number of text inputs:

Laravel prioritizes the files, and the text inputs may not be visible in $request->all('images').


When the number of text inputs exceeds the number of files:

The text inputs will appear in $request->all('images').



Debugging:
You can observe this behavior by adding debugging statements in your controller or request class as you change the number of text and files uploaded:
dd($this->input(), $this->all());

Solution
add withValidator() to manually check for text inputs
public function withValidator($validator) {
        $validator->after(function ($validator) {
            if ($this->input('images')) {
                $validator->errors()->add('images', 'Text values are not allowed in the images field.');
            }
        });
    }

'images' => ['nullable', 'array'],
'images.*' => ['file', 'image', 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg', 'max:1024'],

This will allow an empty or null array but will prevent any null values or non-images from being in the array

It is still the same issue, for some reason a text value is allowed for every image file I have in the request (if I have a single image I can send a single text and no validation error will be thrown, and if I have two images I can send two texts and no validation error will be thrown, but If I have a single image and two texts then I'll get the validation error I want: "message": "The images.1 field must be a file. (and 2 more errors)")

@AhmadAhmad try updated version instead
